# combineReducers not working properly. Can anyone see the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two different reducers in my app => `nodesReducer` and `controlsReducer`

If I pass them to the store once at a time, they work perfectly fine but whenever I use combineReducers, they stop working => as in everything I pull from the state becomes `undefined` in my components but everything still looks normal in the toolkit extension.

This is the code.

This works totally fine (single reducer directly put there):

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import nodesReducer from "./Node";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: nodesReducer,
  middleware: [],
});

export default store;
```

And this one does not work when I add one more reducer with combineReducers:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import nodesReducer from "./Node";
import controlsReducer from "./Controls";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  nodesReducer,
  controlsReducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [],
});

export default store;
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Nick everything I get from the state with useSelector becomes undefined when I use combineReducers so the app crashes.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe the problem in how you implement the reducer? And maybe its on how you use `useSelector`

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an educated guess here, but nothing seems obviously wrong in what you've provided, so given you've *only* changed the reducer code I'd imagine it's because by combining your reducers, your state will change from:

```
{
   ...stuffFromNodesReducer
}
```

Into

```
{
    nodesReducer: ...stuffFromNodesReducer,
    controlsReducer: ...stuffFromControlsReducer
}
```

You should be able to examine your redux state using redux devtools to check how what it looks like.

Comment: This error occurred because of a mistake in the importing from the useSelector

Comment: I don't think you showed that in the code snippet, could you add the error and resolution?

Answer (score 0):

After adding rootReducer you should change your useSelectors from

```
useSelector(state => state.someData)
```

to

```
useSelector(state => state.nodesReducer.someData)
useSelector(state => state.controlsReducer.someData)
```